# How do I turn off Auto capture keyboard in ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

How do I turn off auto capture keyboard in Linux(ubuntu)?

Comment: If Ubuntu is the host, then you would use the right [Ctrl] key.

Answer (score 1):

In Virtualbox at the main screen first click on File then Preferences:

[image]

Then click on the Input tab on the left, then unselect `Auto Capture Keyboard`.

[image]